# Body won't follow rig properly

Tags: rigging

My rig breaks body geometry near the shoulder and I have no idea why. Maybe you know?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably weight painting isn't done correctly so it clipping throught. Maybe try less agressive approach - add 0.2 weights on some vertices around shoulder and see how it reacts.

Comment: as Radoon says, the weight painting must be wrong, you need to check if a wrong bone influence this part, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

You should check weight painting. Did you use automatic option that Blender provides?

It may be good for something but for such wide movement it will start to clip... try to open weight paint, select bone in vertex groups and try to clean it. If you are new it basically means **red is too much** so try to select subtract brush, use 0.2 weight (color should be yellow/orange but not red) and try to move it again.

Comment: I tried it out and this did not totally work for me but it helped to ameliorate the situation. Maybe I need to make more tests.
Anyway, thank you for suggesting.